# Is it possible to transit through a UK airport whilst barred for entry into the UK

Tags: uk, transit, airports, eu-citizens, criminal-records

A particular person wanting to travel is barred for entry to the UK. This means if they set foot on UK soil they will be arrested and put in jail.

This is all ok, however there are a number of good flights which transit through the UK.

Would this person get arrested upon landing in the UK, even though the airport is technically not the UK and they are transiting within a few hours?

This is assuming they do not cross the point of immigration of course.

-- Update

This is based on the assumption the person travelling committed a crime and has been explicitly barred from entry to the UK.

Comment: Is that person even allowed a TWOV based on the nationality?

Comment: @HankyPanky Yes, European national. Would normally be allowed w/o visa, but due to circumstances (entry ban) is not allowed to do so

Comment: "the airport is technically not the UK"  I'm pretty sure that is **totally wrong**, Ninj.   You may be thinking of *embassies*.

Comment: Note similarly there's no "point" of "safety" or the like. As soon as you cross the international boundary of the UK (out in the ocean), the authorities can lay hands on you.

Comment: EU nationals cannot be barred from the UK (yet) unless they've committee a very serious crime.

Comment: See UK transit rules https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/674190/transit-guidance-v2.0ext.pdf

Comment: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/674861/international-travel-bans-v8.0ext.pdf

Comment: @Fattie British airports and foreign embassies in the UK are _all_ part of the UK (and the same thing applies to all countries). The international area of airports is unusual because the normal immigration rules don't apply there; foreign embassies are unusual because the UK agrees not to enter them without permission. But they're all parts of the UK, just parts of the UK with unusual rules.

Comment: If the UK police actively wants him for a crime, then that is a much larger problem for him than merely being "barred from entry". I strongly suspect that either the "barred from entry" part or the "will be arrested and put in jail" part of the background must be a misunderstanding of the facts, either on the part of the OP or on the "friend".

Comment: hey @DavidRicherby !  Yes, as I said, I believe the OP was thinking about "embassies".  (Where you can "not get arrested".  You can surely get arrested in any part inch of an airport, if you're wanted.)

Answer (score 5):

I have to say, as far as I know, this is probably in the category:

## Inconceivable you would try this  :-o

Researchable fact - people are arrested at airports *all the time*.

It's a favorite hangout of the blokes with guns who arrest people who are enemies of the state for various reasons big and small.

https://www.dailystar.co.uk/news/latest-news/709439/heathrow-airport-man-arrested-suspicion-terrorism-met-police-news

> [Arrested as ..] as he attempted to board a plane at around 11.05pm on Sunday night ...

To be more specific, you can google the specific! airport involved.  Try googling "Arrested at Heathrow airport".

As mentioned in a comment:

*"the airport is technically not the UK..."  This is "incredibly wrong."  It is possible you are thinking of ***embassies***?

Every square inch of Heathrow is "incredibly" under the control of the imperials, it's kind of a "low-rights area."

They specifically, in a number of stages, carefully search for anyone they are "on the lookout for".

---

Here's one!

https://www.getsurrey.co.uk/news/surrey-news/just-reasons-people-been-arrested-13695917

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP is not thinking of embassies, but rather is confused by the signage placed at the border checkpoint, which implies that before crossing that checkpoint you haven't entered the country. However, if OP were thinking of embassies they would be equally wrong: embassies remain the territory of the host nation.

Comment: This is not even true for embassies.

Comment: I'm just researching if it's even feasible, ie whether or not it's *allowed*. Since I was thinking that transiting through the airport (not even getting out to immigration) wouldn't be the same as entering the country and then breaching the conditions of entry

Comment: @code ninja If the airline requires you to submit API before check-in the ban may flag up and you may not be allowed to board https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/300741/CarrierInformation.pdf

Comment: Hi Ninj.   "Since I was thinking that transiting through the airport (not even getting out to immigration) wouldn't be the same as entering the country..."   Yes, just to be clear that is **totally wrong**.  It's totally commonplace that people are arrested in the plane, on the tarmac, in the pre-customs queue, or anywhere else.  Sorry@!